# Pause/Resume Timer when interrupted by keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

Create a timer in python starting from 00:00:00. The timer should pause/resume if interrupted by keyboard. Please help me undestand how to use KeyboardInterrupt to pause/resume timer.

```
import time
def timer():
    for i in range(12):
        for j in range(60):
            for k in range(60):
                try:
                    print("{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(i,j,k))
                    time.sleep(1)
                # except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    # print('Break')
```

Comment: suggestion: use `f strings` (python 3.6 and above) since they are a bit easier to read. For example in this case: `f"{i:02d}:{j:02d}:{k:02d}"` could be used in the `print()` funciton.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow this approach

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but worked

```
import time

def timer(pause_i, pause_j, pause_k):
    for i in range(pause_i, 12):
        for j in range(pause_j, 60):
            for k in range(pause_k, 60):
                try:
                    print(f"{i:02d}:{j:02d}:{k:02d}")
                    time.sleep(1)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    try:
                        input('\nCtrl+C to resume\n')
                    except KeyboardInterrupt:
                        timer(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1)

timer(0, 0, 0)
```

I think it's a better way to use `key = input('...')` to resume the timer, such as

```
key = input('\ninput r to resume : ')
if key == 'r':
    timer(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This gave me the idea that the `input()` will interrupt the kernel and system will just wait for the any external input and continues after it. So I just changed the `print()` under `except KeyboardInterrupt` in my original code to `input('\nPress any key\n')` and it worked. Now I might be missing something, please try it out and let me know if I got that right